# Как сделать масштабирование изображений?

Tags: изображения, java, масштабирование

На `jpanel` при помощи класса `graphics` нарисовано изображение. Необходимо сделать масштабирование данного изображения при нажатии на клавишу (увеличение и масштабирование изображения), и при масштабировании должны появляться полосы прокрутки, если изображение не влазит все на `jpanel`. Как это сделать, может где примеры есть какие?
P.s. Для добавления полос прокрутки возможно нужно добавить `jpanel` на `scrollpane`.

Answer (score 1):

[Displaying a Scaled Image with Java Swing](http://movingtofreedom.org/2007/11/11/displaying-a-scaled-image-in-java/)

Comment: Ссылки-ответы не приветствуются на ru.SO. Сделайте краткий ответ из поста.